# Why Interceptors execute as normal after ExceptionMapper in Apache CXF?

Tags: java, rest, cxf, jax-rs, interceptor

I have implemented some **RESTful web services** with some in and out `Interceptors` Using **Apache CXF (version 2.7.5)**. I have also implemented an `ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException>` to catch the cases where an not existed resource is accessed and to return a custom response to the user.

**ExceptionMapper**

```
@Provider
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException>{
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(NotFoundException exception) {
        Response response = Response
                .status(Status.NOT_FOUND)
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .entity("{\"message\":\"The resource that you tried to access does not exist.\"}").build();
        return response;
    }
}
```

I noticed that when I access a resource that does not exist my exception mapper is invoked and builds a custom `Response` which is fine. My problem is that after my exception mapper is invoked then my interceptors are being executed which is something that I want to avoid.

Is there any way to identify in an interceptor that `MyExceptionMapper` has been invoked and call `return`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After CXF uses an [ExceptionMapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html), it will send the message through the normal outgoing interceptor chain, and not the fault interceptor chain.

One solution might be setting a value on the CXF Message [Exchange](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/message/Exchange.html) from within your ExceptionMapper, e.g.

```
PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage()
.getExchange().put("com.test.skip", Boolean.TRUE);
```

You could then retrieve and test for that value in your Interceptors.

```
Boolean skip = (Boolean) PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage()
.getExchange().get("com.test.skip");
```